# Merge tags [fql] and [facebook-fql]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

They both refer to Facebook Query Language. I suspect it would be better to merge [fql](/questions/tagged/fql)x852 to [facebook-fql](/questions/tagged/facebook-fql)x1216 and make a synonym from former to latter.

Comment: I proposed this synonym. If you've got the reputation, please vote up at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/tags/fql/synonyms

Answer (score 3):

+1 I was about to propose this merge when I found this post. It's important to recognize that if someone uses the plain [fql](/questions/tagged/fql) tag without an additional "facebook" tag, then their post won't automatically show up on [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/).

I also notice many people [using them both together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-fql+fql), probably to "cover all bases", which is a telltale sign tags should be merged.